# Events on a JPanel which has a Border Layout

Tags: java, swing, listener, jpanel, border-layout

When I add a MouseListener/FocusListener to a JPanel which has a BorderLayout and JComponents in it, I can't catch mouse or focus events. Is there any way to catch a JPanel's mouse and focus events which has a BorderLayout?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Application extends JFrame{

    public Application(){
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel jPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        jPanel.add(new JButton("Button"));

        jPanel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("mouseExited");
            }
        });

//        if border is set then listener works if not does not
//        jPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black, 1));
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(jPanel);
        setSize(400, 400);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[]args){
        new Application().setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: 1) can you please post code that demonstrate your issue(s) in http://sscce.org/ form, 2) LayoutManager (in your case BorderLayout) has nothing to do with MouseEvents

Comment: But when i instantiate a JPanel and put two jbuttons in it(center and top of it) mouse and focus event of jpanel does not work

Comment: I guess it is becouse the area which belongs to component is not belong to its container. That's why border layouted container cant fire mouse and focus event becouse all area is belong to its components

Comment: that the reason why I asked you to post SSCCE here, be sure that here is only small mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said, just a simple mistake. Because `JFrame` is given a `FlowLayout`, the `JPanel` occupies the area required for `JButton` only. You can test that by adding a `Border` to the `JPanel`.

Now it works,

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Application extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Application() {
        JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
        jPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        jPanel.add(new JButton("Button"));
        jPanel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("mouseExited");
            }
        });
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(jPanel);
        setSize(400, 400);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Application().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following Code prints the corresponding Events to StdOut.

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JPanel innerPanel = new JPanel();
    innerPanel.setSize(200,200);
    panel.add(innerPanel);
    panel.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("MouseReleased");
        }
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("MousePressed");
        }
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("MouseExited");
        }
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("MouseEntered");
        }
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("MouseClicked");
        }
    });

    frame.setContentPane(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);`
```

Comment: that works but the inner component was not a panel it was button.